# VEGA LITE : stacked bar spacing between categories with fixed order

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I got stuck with developing my stacked bar chart in Vega-Lite when attempting to create a space between categories and set a fixed order of categories.

So I don't want the categories ("Funding Income", "Other", "Expenses", "Earned Income") to be blended together but to have a little space between each of them.

Also, the order in the bar should be fixed as follows: "Funding Income", "Other", "Expenses", "Earned Income"; however, I couldn't make it work properly.

Could anyone help out, please?
Thanks"

Here is a sample :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 7000,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Earned Income",
        "Value": 3000,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Other",
        "Value": 500,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Expenses",
        "Value": 8000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Other",
        "Value": 1000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 8000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 6000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Other",
        "Value": 700,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Earned Income",
        "Value": 3000,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Other",
        "Value": 1100,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 4000,
        "Type": "plan"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Expenses",
        "Value": 5000,
        "Type": "reality"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet": {
    "column": {
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "nominal",
      "header": {
        "labelOrient": "bottom",
        "labelFont": "Arial black",
        "labelColor": "black",
        "title": null
      }
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "height": 164,
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "bar",
          "cornerRadius": 1,
          "stroke": "#363636",
          "strokeWidth": 1.5
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "Type",
            "axis": {
              "labelAngle": 0,
              "labelOffset": 0
            },
            "title": null
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "Value",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "title": null
          },
          "xOffset": {"field": "Type"},
          "color": {
            "field": "Group",
            "sort": [
              "Funding Income",
              "Other",
              "Expenses",
              "Earned Income"
            ],
            "scale": {
              "domain": [
                "Funding Income",
                "Other",
                "Expenses",
                "Earned Income"
              ],
              "range": [
                "gray",
                "white",
                "lightgray",
                "black"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a sort order like this?

[image]

If so, add an order:

```
"order":{"sort": "descending", "field":"Group"},
```

Regarding the space between stacks, this is a bit nuanced. You can either:

1. Explode
2. Erode

If you explode, then you can no longer have a Y axis as it wouldn't make sense. If you erode, then the smaller values may disappear. Either way, there is no built in functionality to do this but if you want to go the explosion route, then you can copy the technique from my sankey example here which involves introducing dummy values for the spaces:

https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#sankey-chart

**UPDATE**
[image]
This sorts the stacks using a calculate transform and order encoding. To sort the legend, just change the order of your domain/range as desired.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 7000, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Other", "Value": 500, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 8000, "Type": "reality"},
      {"Year": 2022, "Group": "Other", "Value": 1000, "Type": "reality"},
      {
        "Year": 2022,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 8000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {
        "Year": 2021,
        "Group": "Funding Income",
        "Value": 6000,
        "Type": "reality"
      },
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Other", "Value": 700, "Type": "reality"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Earned Income", "Value": 3000, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Other", "Value": 1100, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Funding Income", "Value": 4000, "Type": "plan"},
      {"Year": 2021, "Group": "Expenses", "Value": 5000, "Type": "reality"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "indexof(['Funding Income','Other','Expenses','Earned Income'], datum.Group)",
      "as": "sort"
    }
  ],
  "facet": {
    "column": {
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "nominal",
      "header": {
        "labelOrient": "bottom",
        "labelFont": "Arial black",
        "labelColor": "black",
        "title": null
      }
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "height": 164,
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "bar",
          "cornerRadius": 1,
          "stroke": "#363636",
          "strokeWidth": 1.5
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "Type",
            "axis": {"labelAngle": 0, "labelOffset": 0},
            "title": null
          },
          "order": {"sort": "ascending", "field": "sort"},
          "y": {"field": "Value", "type": "quantitative", "title": null},
          "xOffset": {"field": "Type"},
          "color": {
            "field": "Group", 
            "scale": {
              "domain": [
                "Funding Income",
                "Other",
                "Expenses",
                "Earned Income"
              ],
              "range": ["gray", "white", "lightgray", "black"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly I would like to manually determine (hard-code) the order how categories are displayed in the bar...hmm, I okay so the spacing is harder than I thought..I try to experience with dark colors and white strokes on the bars...thank you!

Comment: It's hard to understand the sort order you want when everything is shades of grey and not all groups are present in each stack. If you clarify the question, I can try again. Also, are you talking about the legend, the stacks or both?

Comment: apologies..what I mean is that I want to specify the order in which the stacks go from bottom to  the top of the bar...for example if I specify this order of stacks: ("Funding Income", "Other", "Expenses", "Earned Income"), then on the bottom of the bar I will see stack "Funding Income" followed above by "Other"...and "Earned Income" on the top of the bar...and yes, both, the stacks and legend should be in line...

Comment: I'll update now.